# Why does dragging generate blue blocks on an HTML page?

Tags: html, browser

I notice that if you open any page, say youtube.com, and you drag the mouse with the left button held down that large blocks of blue will appear, that don't seem to have any relation to where the mouse is being dragged.   In the image below from youtube.com, for example, I held down the left button and dragged the mouse along the red line from left to right and when it reached the point at the right end the areas at the top all turned blue:
[image: blue blocks]

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can stop it?  It's a problem for me because I give people a page where they can draw things and one of the of the operations is to drag a box around several items to group them, but the drag is causing unrelated things on the page to turn blue.

Thanks

Comment: because on mouse drag, the default behavior is content (DOM) selection. See this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select an element it highlights the entire element.

You can use CSS to disable user selection on specific elements with:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Alternatively with JavaScript you'll need to prevent the default behavior for `mousedown` events so that the selection is not started.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not selecting the elements that are turning blue. The mouse is way down where the red arrow is.